# flowtype - higher order functions - currying

Tags: flowtype

```
type hof = (f:Function) => Function;

type ty_MiddleWare = (store:StoreType) => hof;
```

How can I type higher order functions ? A function that returns a function that returns a function ?

I am trying to make [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-middleware-chain) code typesafe and the above attempt is not accepted by flow. The problem comes up when using curryed functions.

this is how I indend to use the `ty_MiddleWare`:

```
const addLoggingToDispatch = (store) :ty_MiddleWare=>{
  return (next:Function)=>{
    return (action)=>{
      console.group(action.type);
      console.log('%c prev state','color: gray', store.getState());
      console.log('%c action','color: blue',action);
      const returnValue=next(action);
      console.log('%c next state','color: green',store.getState());
      console.groupEnd();
      return returnValue;
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Which code specifically doesn't work? I just tried your example in the [Try Flow](https://flowtype.org/try) site and it says 'No errors' - could you write a [mcve] which reproduces the issue (also, do you need to update Flow or is it up to date?)

Comment: Thanks, yes, apparently it works without the `addLoggingToDispatch`, need to think about this...

Comment: The whole thing (including `addLoggingToDispatch`) seemed to pass Flow's checks when I pasted it in (and made a dummy `StoreType`). Perhaps that's something to consider?

Comment: OK, thanks, need to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean:
`const addLoggingToDispatch:ty_MiddleWare = (store) => {` ?

The way you wrote it, `addLoggingToDispatch` `return`s your `ty_MiddleWare` type. In my way, you declare `addLoggingToDispatch` to be `ty_MiddleWare`